# FF applies random font-size on :after element (CSS)

Tags: css, firefox

I have this circle-shaped plus symbol that is basically a `<span>` witht the class `plus`. In CSS, I render an :after element which includes the `+` character (`\ff0b`). Strangely, Firefox renders the font-size of the `+` very differently than the normal Plus. Chrome does it right.

In this screenshot, Chrome is left, Firefox is right. I included a normal Plus character before "alle" for comparison. Ignore the grey gradient, that's just a drop-shadow from the browser window:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
 .plus {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    margin-top: -2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 161, 228, 0.8);
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.1em;
 }
 .plus:after {
    content: "\ff0b";
 }
```

The HTML could not be simpler:

```
<span class="plus"></span>+ alle Kategorien
```

Comment: Paste the compiled LESS over here

Comment: What's `$font-size-text`?

Comment: My guess is that the character does not exist in the current font ('Executive'), and FF chooses a different font to display it than than Chrome does.

Comment: Good point, Mr. Alien. I updated the post to show the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you replace your \ff0b with an actual '+', the rendering is the same in both browsers:

```
 .plus:after {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   content: "+";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r47JB/3/

I've also set the font-size and font-weight, to be sure it doesn't inherit.

Comment: My guess is that the OP has their reasons for using a fullwidth plus sign instead.

Comment: Milanzor, great, I didn't know that you could reference characters directly (unmasked) in CSS! Will this work on older browsers as well? Then it seems like a good way to go.
Mr Lister, I dont have particlar reasons, but now that we're on it, what is the difference between a plus and a fullwidth plus?

Comment: Update: It does look good in Arial, but when I use Executive as a font there is a bad vertical offset ([Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/54kwz6z4ebc2pv0/Screenshot%202014-06-13%2020.17.53.png), [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r47JB/9/))

Comment: @bootsmaat An ordinary plus is just a plus (\002D); it exists in all fonts. A fullwidth plus is a different character (\FF0B), and fonts that contain it are more rare. Anyway, I thought that's what you wanted, for some reason.